# Combining multiple flat file into one using SSIS Package

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have 2 files, which is data file and trailer file. I would like to combine these files using SSIS package generated by asp.net program.

To combine the two files, i tried Union all but the duplicated rows will be replaced, I also does not wish the data to be sorted like in merge function. Is there any other way i can combine the two files without doing any filtering, just with copy and paste into a new file?

Thanks

Comment: A DOS command of `COPY File1 + File2 OutputFile` will do what you want. DOn't complicate it with SSIS.

Comment: Union all doesn't remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Union All Transformation doesn't remove duplicates, make sure you are using this component correctly.

You can refer to the following tutorials for a step by step guide:

- [Union All Transformation in SSIS Example](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/union-all-transformation-in-ssis/)

If you are looking to remove duplicates, you can refer to the following guide:

- [SSIS and distinct union](http://tvandesijpe.blogspot.com/2011/01/ssis-and-distinct-union.html)